# An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' VB.net

Tags: vb.net

```
Private client As IFirebaseClient
    
Public Class PersonalData
    Public Property helloBlock() As String = "off"
End Class
    
Private Sub helloToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles helloToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Try

        Dim PD As New PersonalData() With
                {
                .helloBlock = "off"
                }

        Dim save = client.Set("func/", PD) 'To save data to Firebase Database.

        MessageBox.Show("hello off", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    Catch ex As Exception
        If ex.Message = "One or more errors occurred." Then
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to firebase, check your network !", "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End If
    End Try
End Sub
```

in this line Dim save = client.Set("func/", PD) 'To save data to Firebase Database.

error System.NullReferenceException
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

can anyone here help me pls fix this.

Comment: Seems like you didn’t create an instance of an `IFirebaseClient` implementation and assign it to `client` before this.

Comment: can you write an answer pls for me? @Ry-
♦

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

It seems I forgot to initialize it in main_load:

```
Try
      client = New FireSharp.FirebaseClient(fcon)
  Catch ex As Exception
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```